# log4j logging at ERROR level when set at INFO

Tags: log4j

I have log4j.xml as below but it is logging messages at ERROR level. Can you help me identify the problem

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ::%-5p::[%c:%L]::[%t]::%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="d:\Log\test.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ::%-5p::[[%c:%L]::[%t]::%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4j  logs all messages higher than and equal to the threshold.(Or in other words it does not log messages lower than the threshold) See [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9).